# Not able to Read back from COM port using BATCH file run from windows 10

Tags: batch

I am running batch file in windows 10 OS. Device is connected at COM1. I have set up COM1 port settings using mode command in batch file. I am sending camera command gcp to get feedback from Camera.

I used `echo gcp>COM1`. I want to direct COM1 output to txt file. Nothing is read from COM1 port. Any solution?

Comment: Typically COM devices don't just send something. They need a command before. Then a response is generated and send. Most likely your command is sent and the device answers but you were not listening so the answer is lost. The COM port doesn't wait for you if nobody is processing the received data then its gone. So try to use two terminals, one for sending and one for receiving (start receiving before sending something).

Comment: I thought it directs output to file directly. So any suggest command to listen to the port. Is any additional line of coding require to perform this?

Comment: As Señor CMasMas already pointed out Windows batch is a bad choice for your project. Us a programming language you are familiar with or alternatively Python see for example on Windows: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66214236/150978

Comment: Thanks Robert. Will use Python to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong "language".  Don't get me wrong.. I love batch but you are trying to hammer a nail with a screwdriver.

You can use a bit of  [trickery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19489733/batch-file-receive-data-from-the-serial-port-and-write-it-into-txt-file) to get most of the way there, but there will still be the need for human interaction (aka CTRL-Z) to stop the serial port read as long as batch is your medium.

Moreover, you will need to look at the input but the data coming in will probably not be the binary you expect when using cmd.exe as your STDIN or STDOUT.. of this I am unsure.

Serial IO is fairly trivial in *almost* any language.. but batch isn't really a language.. just an advanced command processor.  Some will argue that it is indeed a language but this is semantics that aren't relevant to this conversation.

I hope someone comes along with a better answer but I doubt that they will.